# Is there a simple way to allow all pages extending Page_Controller to share an allowed_action and associated function of the Page_Controller itself?

Tags: inheritance, silverstripe

I have a number of controllers extending my main Page_Controller. Page_Controller has a function (used in the template) for displaying the form in the footer of the page:

```
protected function ContactUsForm() {
    $form = new ContactUsForm($this,'EnquireNow');
    return $form;
}
```

Another function handles the form submission:

```
public function EnquireNow($data, $form) {
    return ContactUsForm::submit($data, $form);
}
```

Submitting the form works for the "Page" page-type, but not for any other page types; an error is displayed that EnquireNow isn't an allowed action. How can I allow the form to be submitted from any page?

Am using version 3.1

Comment: Have you set `private $allowed_actions = array('EnquireNow')` on your `Page_Controller` and called `?flush=1` or `?flush=all` on the page you are having problems with? Any controller that extends `Page_Controller` will inherit the `Page_Controller` `$allowed_actions`, so this should work.

Comment: For security reason $allowed_actions should be declared as private, so any controller that extends Page_Controller should declare its own $allowed_actions array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an $allowed_actions in an Extension class and then apply it to all the controllers.

[Documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller#through-allowed-actions) says: $allowed_actions can be defined on Extension classes applying to the controller.